# Knot invariants which arise as the solution of differential equations along the knot

Tags: knot-theory

Do there exist knot invariants which can be computed by solving some kind of differential equation along the knot?

Comment: The Kontsevich integral is obtained by integrating certain differentials along level sets of the knot: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KontsevichIntegral.html